# Django REST: passing objects by slugs in POST, but deserializing by id

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've been trying hard to solve this problem (being rather new to Django Rest Framework).

Given example models

```
class BigModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    something = models.CharField()
    nested = models.ForeignKey(SmallModel)

class SmallModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField()
```

I basically want to pass the following JSON

```
{"something": "whatever", "nested": "existing name" }
```

which would look up `SmallModel` by the given string and set the correct `nested_id` on `BigModel` once it's deserialized.

I understand that this is partially what `SlugRelatedField` is for, but I had no luck getting that to work.

My current stab at serializers is as follows (where I'm basically doing the look up manually):

```
class BigModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nested = serializers.RelatedField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs['nested'] = SmallModel.objects.get(id=attrs['nested'])

    def validate_nested(self, attrs, source):
        nestedName = attrs[source]
        if SmallModel.objects.get(name=nestedName) is None:
            # Error
        nestedId = Stage.objects.get(name=nestedName).id
        attrs[source] = nestedId
        return attrs

    class Meta:
        model = BigModel
        fields = ('nested', 'something')
```

With this, I'm getting this error:

```
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

which basically means `is_valid()` failed on serializer.

If `nested` field on `BigModelSerializer` is set to be `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, then the validation doesn't even get called...